# Authenticating to the Google Admin Directory API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how to authenticate to the Admin Directory API. My goal is to be able to create new GSuite users.

I have followed this guide https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/CreatingClientSecretsFile to setup a client/id secret and service account with Domain-Wide Delegation.

I can successfully get a bearer token, however when I try to make a request to an endpoint I get a 403. I would expect I should be authenticated to this endpoint as I can successfully get all data using GAM, which is using the same credentials.

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'google/apis/admin_directory_v1'

scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"]

authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('service_account.json'),
  scope: scope)

pload = authorizer.fetch_access_token!
token = pload["access_token"]

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/my@email.com"
uri = URI.parse(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{token}"

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

p response #=> <Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>
```

Comment: What exact error does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the scopes on the Service Account and everything works fine.